# npm install react-bootstrap erroring

Tags: npm-install, react-bootstrap

My code is importing components from react-bootstrap

```
import { FormGroup, ControlLabel } from "react-bootstrap";
```

I am running

```
npm install react-bootstrap
```

inorder to install the package when I do I get this error

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: react-bootstrap-validtion@latest
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for react-popper@1.2.1
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

I attempted then to npm install react-popper@1.2.1 but that too errored
How can I fix this

Answer (score 1):

The versions for react-popper are 1.2.0 or 1.3.0.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-popper[Version page of react-popper][1]

No version 1.2.1 is available.

Answer (score 0):

There is no react -popper version 1.2.1 which you are trying to install please go through the react-popper versions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-popper)

For react bootstrap installation please refer [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#installation)

If these do not help you solve your problem please let us know

Comment: I followed the React-bootstrap doc for installation and still receiving the same error

Comment: i tried the above snippet for installation it worked fine for me. If you don't mind can you share the screen shot of your command line

Answer (score 0):

It is a better practice to install both react-bootstrap and bootstrap itself, If you try to install bootstrap along react-bootstrap using this code you should get out of the errors

```
 npm install bootstrap react-bootstrap
```